# How to refresh folder view layout in KDE?

Tags: kde, kubuntu, plasma5, plasma

I set my desktop layout to folder view and displaying the contents of a folder in my external drive. When I remove the drive, every icon in my desktop disappears which is understandable. But when I plug it in again, the icons doesn't show up. Right clicking and refreshing desktop doesn't work. Only thing that solves my issue is going to the desktop settings and selecting another folder to display and then selecting back to my original folder. The issue I'm facing is something similar to [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/comments/d4zcpg/how_to_manually_refresh_desktop_icons_in_plasma/). Is there a way to solve this?

- OS: Ubuntu 18.04
- DE: Kubuntu 18.04
- KDE Plasma Version: 5.12.9
- KDE Frameworks Version: 5.44.0
- Qt Version: 5.9.5

Comment: It seems that this is a [bug](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=413609).